# XML replace content to other

Tags: php, xml

i have this script:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$xml='../assets/local.xml';
$dom->load($xml);
$cdata=$dom->createCDATASection('95.55.4.2');
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('connection') as $item) {
    $item->getElementsByTagName('host')->item(0)->appendChild($cdata);
}
$dom->save($xml);
```

And my xml is:

```
<connection>
<host>localhost</host>
</connection>
```

and i need to change "localhost" to "95.55.4.2" with CData. I try this scrip but he wrong... that is the result:

```
<connection>
<host>95.55.4.2localhost</host>
</connection>
```

Any can help me please

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nodeValue` to set the node value directly:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$xml='../assets/local.xml';
$dom->load($xml);

# access the element directly: it's the first "host" node in the doc:
$dom->getElementsByTagName('host')->item(0)->nodeValue = '95.55.4.2';

$dom->save($xml);
```

Using `appendChild` will add your CDATA node to the existing child nodes, which is why you are getting the combination of the old and new strings.